# Div in the center with specific width, sides must scale with screen

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying get 3 div's to fit aside eachother, the two side divs need to fill the rest of the page equally:

```
    <div class="second_bar">
        <div class="status_border_left">
        </div><div class="nav_bar">
        </div><div class="status_border_right">
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.status_border_left{
    //width:100px;
    height:14px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.status_border_right{
    //width:100px;
    height:14px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.nav_bar{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:80px;
    width:980px;
    background-color:green;
}
.second_bar *{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.second_bar{
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Any way to do what I want without involving JavaScript?

Comment: Is there a `.status_bar` block element somewhere? your HTML may be missing it... please check. Thank you.

Comment: edited it out, sorry about that it is unrelated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it by using CSS display types of `table` and `table-cell`.

You need to make a small modification to your left and right child elements, simply define a wrapper `.content` div to enclose any content.

The **HTML**:

```
<div class="second_bar">
    <div class="status_border left">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav_bar"></div>

    <div class="status_border right">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the **CSS**:

```
.second_bar {
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    display: table;
}
.status_border {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.status_border .content {
    width: auto;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: pink;
}
.nav_bar {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 80px;
    width: 980px;
    min-width: 980px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

For your container block `.second_bar`, set the display type to `table` and the width to 100%.

The child elements `.status_border` and `.nav_bar` have `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: top`, but you may adjust that depending on your layout requirements.

The `.nav_bar` child div has a width of 980px, but because it is a table cell, the width could shrink to less than 980px if the window is small enough.  Table cell's will shrink to fit the content if needed.  To maintain the full width, set the `min-width` to the width.

To get your left and right status indicator bars to be 14px high, you need to have a separate block element with the left and right child elements.

By default, the three `table-cell` blocks will take the height of the tallest of the three table cells, in this case, the 80px `.nav_bar` div.

If you set `.content`'s width to auto, it will both will take on the same width and fill up the rest of the available page width.

Note that `table-cell` is not supported in IE8, but otherwise, this is a pretty useful pattern.

See demo fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/SyAAQ/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the css3 flexbox module. like this:

#### HTML

```
<div class="second_bar">
  <div class="status_border_left">left</div>
  <div class="nav_bar">nav bar</div>
  <div class="status_border_right">right</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.second_bar {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;

  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.status_border_left,
.status_border_right {
  width: 20%;
  background: green;
}
.nav_bar {
  -moz-flex-box: 1;
  -webkit-flex-box: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/aznwA).

Comment: Your answer worked great but Marc Audet's has an explanation as well. +1 For making me discover Flex...

Answer (score 0):

you need float

```
div1{
float:left;
}

div2{
float:left
}
```

Comment: Floating will cause these div's to shrink-to-fit their content, so how will they know to fill up the remaining width of the containing block?

Comment: specify the width in those two div, because without width, height doesn't work

Comment: thats what I tried, I only commented out the width so you guys dont say: "the problem is the width at 100px!"