# Responsive Web Design 3 equal height columns

Tags: html, css, web

For responsive design I'm trying to have 3 equal height columns, but one of these columns is an image that resizes.  I've been able to have 3 equal height text columns, but adding an image messes things up.  I need the columns to resize to be the height of the image as it is being resized when a user shrinks his browser.

For example.
20% text column with blue background.
20% text column with red background
60% column with just an image that resizes.

Whats the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far so we can help you.

Comment: That's going to be almost impossible, unless you crop the image at certain breakpoints

Comment: What you are asking for is very similar to a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157058/div-in-the-center-with-specific-width-sides-must-scale-with-screen

Comment: The only way this problem makes sense is if the image div controls the height and the two other div's (blue and red) have equal widths that take up the remainder of the containing block's width.

Comment: Yes, how do I make the image div control the height of the other two columns?

Comment: A few questions: (1) Will you have any content/text in the red/blue side(?) columns? or else, will these have a minimum width? (2) will the image be static or dynamic, and will these images be in portrait or landscape mode?

Comment: Yes, a small amount of content will be in the red/blue columns.  These will have a minimum width.  The image will be static and is landscape.

Comment: Okay, that helps, let me work on it... I will post something for you in a few minutes. What is the order of your elements, blue, red, image?

Comment: yes, blue, red, image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get started on a flexible layout.

Your HTML could look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bookend left">
        <div class="content">You can put text in here...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bookend right">
        <div class="content">or here as you need.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-panel">
        <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/400/300">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    display: table;
}
.bookend {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.bookend .content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
    text-align: left;
}
.image-panel {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: green;
}
.image-panel img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
div.bookend.left {
    background-color: blue;
}
div.bookend.right {
    background-color: red;
}
```

To see how it works, visit the demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/r8LUA/

**How This Works**

I have a parent block `div.wrapper` with three child elements, the right of which holds a landscape image that expands with the window size.

I use the CSS display properties of table and table-cell to get three equal height columns.

If you are adding content to the left and right elements, it helps to place that content in a fixed width child container (pink box).  This is critical if you want the red and blue panels to be the same width.

Comment: Great only thing is it doesn't let me add 10px margin between each of the columns. Not sure why.

Comment: Good point.  This is a limitation of the table-cell approach.  I work around it by adding a spacer column, extra mark-up but it works.  Please see updated demo.  Alternatively, you can use border-spacing if you don't mind space on the far left and the far right.

Answer (score -2):

set `.class img{width: ;heigh: ;` tho the size of your column. This will resize all images to this size.

Comment: The height of the columns varies, though. How do you deal with that?